# Download iOS Twitter Kit

Tags: ios, twitter

Quite irritatingly, the documentation for the Twitter Api (https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios) is quite complete with lots of example and all, but in the whole site I wasn't able to find a single "Download" button.

Now, where can I download the TwitterKit? Thanks

Comment: As of iOS 5 TwitterKit is part of Xcode. In Xcode 6 you can just add it to the rest of your framework in  Build Phases.

Comment: I think that Twitter.framework is part of Xcode, but I don't see TwitterKit.framework.

Comment: Twitter Kit has a direct install link here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation#install-twitter-kit-manually

Answer (score 10):

You need to download fabric tool, register, choose your project and install TwitterKit from this interface.

Sing up now here:
https://fabric.io/sign_up

Fabric Docs:
https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/overview

Comment: You can install TwitterKit without Fabric with Cocoapods: pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 1.15.2'

Comment: i download fabric tool,then login,choose my project and Run Script  follow these procedure  i get fabric framework not Twitter Kit so  how to find Twitter Kit

Comment: You also not provide steps only give link.. IT does not help give proper steps in answer.

Answer (score 6):

TwitterKit is part of Fabric, which can be downloaded from https://dev.twitter.com
Follow the link that says "Download".

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for and download Fabric via https://get.fabric.io (which is linked from the Fabric section of https://dev.twitter.com as stated in other responses).